# React (Preact) renders content twice

Tags: reactjs, preact

On an editable pre-element I run a onKeyDown script only when the enter key is pressed to avoid unwanted HTML-elements in the text.

```
render({}, {content}) {
        console.log("render: "+content);
        return <p contenteditable onKeyDown={this.handleKeyDown}>{content}</p>
}
```

In the `handleKeyDown` function the paragraphs content is changed and `setState(content: newText)` is being called so that the content shall be rendered again. This results the new text being written twice.

When I type "hello world" and break after "hello" it will result in
"hello 
worldhello 
world"

Even though the handleKeyDown and render function logs the correct string:
"hello
 world"

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

when using `contentEditable`, you should generally use `dangerouslySetInnerHTML` to set the HTML content.

```
  <div
    contentEditable
    dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{
      __html: value
    }}
  />
```

Here's a [working JSFiddle example](https://jsfiddle.net/developit/nLfbjmaz/) showing how to do just that.

Comment: Thanks! This did the trick. I even remember stumbling upon this `dangerouslySetInnerHTML` but without any explanation on what it's all about.